# drive api: list files in trash bin

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

Is there any way to only list the trashed files?
For my current project, I just need to know if the trash bin empty or not.

note: I'm using python 3 and drive API v2 with PyDrive

Thanks for your attention.Hope you will try to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to check whether there are the trashed files.
- You want to achieve this using pydrive of python.

In this case, how about using `ListFile` method with the search query of `trashed=true`? By this, when the returned value has the values, it indicates that the trashed files are existing. When this is reflected to a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
drive = GoogleDrive(auth) # Please use your "auth".

res = drive.ListFile({'q': "trashed=true"}).GetList()
if not res:
    print("No trashed files.")
else:
    print("Trashed files are found.")
```

#### References:

- [ListFile(param=None)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/pydrive.html?highlight=listfile#pydrive.drive.GoogleDrive.ListFile)
- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)